# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode - django python

Tags: python, django, unicode

```
comment_json = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.places4two.de/location/"+locname+"/"+str(lid)+"/")
comment_dict = json.loads(comment_json.read())
```

if I print `comment_dict`, i am getting dict in this form this:

```
{u'http://www.places4two.de/location/date-in-caroussel/2406/': 
{u'comments': 
   {u'paging': 
     {u'cursors': {u'after': u'MQ==', u'before': u'Mg=='}}, 
     u'data': [
        {u'from': {u'name': u'John Purlore', u'id': u'100005454794537'}, 
        u'like_count': 0, 
        u'can_remove': False, 
        u'created_time': u'2013-10-30T09:02:51+0000', 
        u'message': u'Essen ist richtig lecker\n', 
        u'id': u'573597026010502_13875759', 
        u'user_likes': False},
               ]
     }
    }
   }
```

and now I just want to check if `data` has some value or not:

```
if comment_dict['http://www.places4two.de/location/'+locname+'/'+str(lid)+'/']['comments']['data']:
```

but in this line, i am getting the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

what am i doing wrong? `locname` is locationname and `str(lid)` is string version of location_id - so they are variables.

isnot it because of `str()`?

Comment: I don't believe that you have shown the faulty case: http://ideone.com/JTsusD. More likely you've hit a case where one of `comment_dict` or `comment_dict[url]` or `comment_dict[url]['comments']` is an empty list `[]` rather than a dictionary, if that's permitted by the facebook API you're using.

Comment: can You find out which of `[]` return this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.get()` instead of `[]`

```
url = 'http://www.places4two.de/location/'+locname+'/'+str(lid)+'/'
if comment_dict.get(url).get('comments').get('data'):
     #my code.
```

To do this safely (Not run into `NoneType has no attribute` issues ), you could also do:

```
url = 'http://www.places4two.de/location/'+locname+'/'+str(lid)+'/'
if comment_dict.get(url, {}).get('comments', {}).get('data', None):
     #my code.
```

Comment: `.get()` returns `None` by default. The final `.get('data', None)` call could be shortened to `.get('data')`.

Comment: In this case `KeyError` should be raised not `TypeError`

Comment: so i dont need ``urllib2`` even?

Comment: You do need `urllib2` - This is just the dictionary parsing logic.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX Agreed, but I wanted to just show it explicitly so that the OP can choose to do `.get('data', [])`

Comment: yeah, thanks, that was stupid question. i deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

This is because data returns a list of objects, while you're likely accessing it like a dictionary.

Try this:

```
data = comment_dict['http://www.places4two.de/location/'+locname+'/'+str(lid)+'/']['comments']['data']
if len(data) > 0 and data[0].get("like_count"):
     # code for when like_count is greater than 0
```